# Controllers that have no model, Laravel MVC pattern

Tags: php, model-view-controller, architecture, laravel, laravel-4

When designing laravel applications within the MVC pattern is it ok to have controllers that are not related to a model?

For example: My app has "Event", "User" and "Activity" models and related controllers. However, the application dashboard will be displaying a news feed of events, users and other items. Should I create a DashboardController class? Even if this does not directly relate to a model class?

Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can just make calls to the various models you need from the dashboard controller. I'm doing something similar myself at the moment and I have a dashboard controller in the works.

MVC doesn't mean that every C has to have an M or even a V. ;) Think of it as an overall pattern/structure and not that each has to be linked to the next level.

Comment: although is this best practice? having controllers that have no model relating to them directly?

Comment: Sure, you don't want to end up having a *Dashboard method in each controller. You can simply call each of those models in your Dash controller and build up the data you need to show.

Comment: Think of MVC as a suggested structure for separation of your code. Not an enforced ruleset that means every part of your app has to have all 3 parts.

Comment: (Example) you don't have a dashboardcontroller, and over the years your application has grown to over 20 different dashboards. When a vital change has to be made in your dashboard, lets say `AuthorizationAttributes`. You would have to edit this in every controller you have that holds a dashboardmethod. And again if the `AuthorizationAttribute` changes. In the case of a seperate controller for dashboards your changes would be on a single file, or even a single method. This is a blessing when working with customer's shifting requirements.